# advérbio + adjetivo + substantivo é correcto?

Tags: gramática, adjetivos, advérbios

Ouvi um professor dizendo o seguinte:

> Ontem mesmo eu estava lendo uma tradução que um sujeito fez de uma matéria inglesa. Eu não lembro exatamente as palavras, mas vou tentar criar um equivalente aqui: “**A horrivelmente hipócrita sociedade britânica**”. Isso não é português; isso é inglês com palavras brasileiras. Em português você não pode fazer isso. Você não pode anteceder um advérbio, um adjetivo e depois um substantivo, porque não funciona. No entanto, o número de pessoas que escreve assim hoje é enorme.

Há regra gramatical para que não seja assim ou é questão de estilo? Se for estranho/errado essa construção, qual serial uma melhor para o exemplo dado, i.e., horrivelmente hipócrita ou esteticamente bonita?

Comment: Quando diz a sequência de 3 advérbio + adjetivo + substantivo quer com isso dizer o exemplo: *"horrivelmente hipócrita sociedade"*?

Comment: @bad_coder, sim.

Comment: Acho que é melhor se editares a pergunta para acrescentar alguma enfase à sequência. Talvez usando negrito ou escrevendo a passagem em questão fora da citação, como está escrito o post não diz qual é exactamente a construção sobre a qual perguntas.

Comment: Vejo zero problemas com essa frase (ou mais exatamente, sintagma). Talvez devesses perguntar ao professor donde foi que ele tirou essa ideia.

Comment: @Artefacto, ia comentar que concordava contigo mas, quando fui procurar exemplos existentes ou inventados que me soassem bem, não consegui encontrar nenhum. Será que a presença do advérbio não torna a ordem inversa estranha demais?

Comment: Imagino que realmente possa soar normal para algumas pessoas e para outras não. Mas pode ser que soe normal apenas porque já estão acostumados com o errado, assim como algumas pessoas não percebem nada de errado com gerundismos.

Comment: Então o professor (o que professa, gente) aceitaria: “A sociedade britânica, horrivelmente hipócrita, pensa que etc etc. ". Para mim o maior problema surge desse horrivelmente como tradução literal. horribly aqui seria: intensamente, por exemplo. A sociedade britânica, intensamente hipócrita, etc.

Comment: @Lambie, entretanto, em vosso exemplo, colocastes as características da sociedade britânica entre vírgulas - não me ocorre o nome gramatical dessa construção agora. Creio que o vosso exemplo soe mais natural ao idioma português.

Answer (score 1):

Essa professora deve ter ouvido, não gostado e ignorado conhecimentos da língua. A frase está muito bem montada, não é só uma questão de "advérbio + adjetivo + substantivo", as coisas na sintaxe são hierárquicas, o advérbio está modificando o adjetivo, que, por sua vez, está encaixado com o substantivo. Talvez a reclamação da professora tenha a ver com a colocação de "horrivelmente hipócrita", quiçá preferisse "a sociedade britânica horrivelmente hipócrita", mas esta não está mais certa, nem mais errada, pois usamos adjetivos antepostos aos substantivos com muita freqüência.

Comment: Ergative Man, concordo com o que fala, mas acho que poderia falar da figura de linguagem que constitui essa alteração de ordem. Acho que melhoraria sua resposta e daria mais crença aos que duvidam.+1